# Codeigniter active record update not working but works on adding a dummy statement

Tags: database, codeigniter, activerecord

A codeigniter code sequence is behaving rather strangely.
In a model, the code below don't work and don't update the database:

```
$this->db->set($data);
$this->db->where($this->_primaryKey, $id);
$this->db->update($this->_tableName);
```

while if I add a dummy instruction just before them and make the sequence look like as shown below

```
$this->db->update('pages', array('body'=>'hhfhj@gmail.com'), "id = 7"); 
//The above statement need not to have any connection with the table I am updating.
// But unless I add the above statement, the statement below are not able to update the database.

$this->db->set($data);
$this->db->where($this->_primaryKey, $id);
$this->db->update($this->_tableName);
```

I don't understand, what that extra statement does that codeigniter active record function starts to work and not otherwise.

The query generated in first case is:

```
"UPDATE `users` SET `name` = 'Shashank Jagetiya', `email` = 'other@gmail.com', `password` = 'a' WHERE `id` != '2' AND `id` = 2"
```

The query generated in second case is:

```
"UPDATE `users` SET `name` = 'Shashank Jagetiya', `email` = 'adfddfaf@gmail.com', `password` = 'a' WHERE `id` = 2"
```

Ok, I understand that some previous condition stays or something...I don't see, where that is coming from or how to remove that

Comment: did you print last query ?

Comment: Please post your full code, means content of $data.

Comment: if previous condition stays, you can use `$this->db->reset();` before start of your update section.

Comment: I have posted the queries in both the case. so the $data is also pretty much clear. That extra part after where in first case  `id` != '2', I don't understand where it has come from

Comment: Can you please post the result of the echo from last query?

Comment: Instead of `$this->db->where($this->_primaryKey, $id);`, you try this `$this->db->where('id', $id);`. This will help us to understand regarding the where clause.

Comment: still the same thing Reena
"UPDATE `users` SET `name` = 'Shashank Jagetiya', `email` = 'adfdfdfaf@gmail.com', `password` = '' WHERE `id` != '2' AND `id` = 2".

Comment: $this->db->reset();
this give error saying method doesn't exist

Comment: You must be setting it somewhere in an additional place somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your issue is here:

```
WHERE `id` != '2'
```

While that 2 will be casted to a numeric type, the implicit casting will convert it to a float, and I'll bet your datatype for that column is an int.

Please consult this entry on [casting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html). I recommend not using '2' in this case as it could yield unexpected results, as above.

Additionally, this statement

```
`id` != '2' AND `id` = 2"
```

Even if you weren't casting, this would always resolve to false.

```
`id` != 2 AND `id` = 2
```

Comment: Yeah, the data type is indeed integer, but I do use intval($id) before using it

Comment: But what is being generated in your query is still passing 2 as a string, which will cause a cast to float in the query engine on the MySQL side of things. Additionally, see point two.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am still not able to resolve this. I even hard coded '2' and 2 instead of $id to check any difference but found none. How should I solve this. Please help...

Comment: How come that extra line of code helped me...please suggest

Comment: Did you see my second point above? You're using logic that will always resolve to false in your WHERE clause, so your WHERE will never succeed.

Comment: Rock on, glad I could help!